# UIImage from xcassets returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display a Circle image with red color.
The image is an SVG file exported from the SF Symbols app.

Just Two lines of codes to display a circle image on my iPhone.
but this does not work on iPhone 5s.

```
imgView.image = UIImage(named: "circle.fill")
imgView.tintColor = .systemRed
```

Set image on the storyboard also doesn't work.

Running `po UIImage(named: "circle.fill")` in debugger returns `nil`.

Working
macOS 11.2.3 (macCatalyst)
iPhone 12 mini 14.4.2
iPhone 12 Pro max simulator 14.4.0

NOT Working.
iPhone 5s 12.5.2
iPhone SE simulator 12.4

It seems that the problem is iOS Version.
But I cannot find how to deal with this problem.

**BUILD ENVIRONMENT.**
macOS 11.2.3
Xcode 12.4 (12D4e)

Comment: SVG `UIImage`s are only supported since iOS 13. See the duplicate for other ways.